# Django: Tracking average values of a table

Tags: python, django

I just started working on a little side project for my uni, which aims to provide a platform to offer/search for professional tutoring. To prevent malicious database entries, the Subject model comes with a choice set of 'supported' subjects.

Further, I want to keep track of the average price per hour of every subject as a reference value and I was wondering how to realize that.

With regards to the relationship, the Subject Model has a ForeignKeyField pointing to the User. However, I'm not quite sure how to implement the average price per hour for a specific subject.

My idea wars to write a post safe method which calculates the average price per hour and overwrites a global class variable. Still, this seems pretty insufficient considering that every offer insert would trigger a data base query.

How would you guys approach this issue?

Best,
D.

Comment: Possibly a middle model for `SubjectTutor` that contains a foreign key to a user and subject along with the price... Then you can just average out the cost with a db query of these models.. as to how it actually works with your project though I'm not sure

Comment: Might be a good question for programmers.stackexchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, you want to be able to associate multiple `User`s with each `Subject` and vice versa. With your current `Foreign Key` relation this will be hard to do. As far as the average price per hour goes, Django's QuerySet has a function `aggregate()`:

```
from django.db.models import Avg
class Subject(models.Model):
    ...
    def avg_price_per_hour(self):
        # returns None if no SubjectUser is related to this instance
        return self.subject_tutors.aggregate(Avg('price_per_hour'))

class Tutor(models.Model):
    ...

class SubjectTutor(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='subject_tutors')
    tutor = models.ForeignKey(Tutor, related_name='subject_tutors')
    price_per_hour = model.DecimalField(...)
```

Comment: Awesome thanks :) That did the job!

Comment: Do you guys know whether it is possible to do migrations with this functional properties? Thanks.